# Ubuntu and VLC can't read disk

Tags: 14.04, vlc, cd

I have a CD with a movie I want to watch, but neither can I open the CD in Ubuntu, nor can I open it with VLC. I'm on a laptop, running 14.04.

I have tried running the CD on another laptop running Windows 7, and it couldn't read it either, but when I tried it on a computer running Windows XP, it could be read. I've tried running other CD's on the same laptop, and it works, so it's not the drive (even though I've had trouble with DVD's before).

This is the VLC output I get when trying to open the disc in VLC:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x109a058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.1
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/sr0 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/sr0 for reading
[0x7f20600013c8] dvdread demux error: DVDRead cannot open source: /dev/sr0
[0x7f2068003bd8] main input error: open of `dvd:///dev/sr0' failed
```

I have installed `libdvdread4`, `regionset` and `libdvdcss`. No luck. When running `sudo regionset` this is the output I get:

```
regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
ERROR: Could not open disc "(null)"!
Please ensure there is a readable CD or DVD in the drive.
```

UPDATE: Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                         8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3                         8:3    0 150.1G  0 part 
└─sda5                         8:5    0 315.5G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 311.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                           11:0    1 514.7M  0 rom  /media/dafta/NEW
```

Comment: post the output of `lsblk`

Comment: Updated the OP with the output

Comment: Why don't you try `sudo regionset /dev/sr0` ?